# Getting the ouput from a powershell command in cmd

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a .bat file, which runs various cmd commands, and also runs the following command

```
powershell -c "Get-Acl -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ESRI\License10.0 | Format-List"
```

The output from that command is

```
Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ESRI\License10.0
Owner  : BUILTIN\Administrators
Group  : CORPOFLONDON\Domain Users
Access : CREATOR OWNER Allow  FullControl
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Users Allow  FullControl
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:BAG:DUD:PAI(A;CIIO;KA;;;CO)(A;CI;KA;;;SY)(A;CI;KA;;;BA)(A;CI;KA;;;BU)
```

I want to loop through the Access values to find a particular user and permission level.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The best way would be to do this in PowerShell, not in CMD.

Comment: I should have added (have now) it is part of a larger batch script

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what you are trying to do. 
In powershell you can use something like this to search for administrators fullcontrol  :

`Get-Acl XXX |select -expand access |?{$_.identityreference -match "admin" -and $_.fileSystemRights -eq "FullControl"}`

Comment: It needs to be done in cmd as it is part of a larger installation script.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should directly use PowerShell and not mix with cmd.

Here is an example:

```
$keyPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ESRI\License10.0"
$target = "SYSTEM"

"ACL check on $keyPath :"

Get-Acl -Path $keyPath |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access |
    ForEach-Object {    
        if($_.IdentityReference -match $target) {
            "$($_.IdentityReference) : $($_.AccessControlType) $($_.RegistryRights)"
        }    
    }
```

Comment: I should have added (have now) it is part of a larger batch script.

Comment: Can you pass the user name and the permission you need to check as arguments when calling the powershell script ? Can you elaborate a little about the general batch file purpose ?

Comment: It is part of a installation package, so once the install is done, the batch file checks where it has copied the appropriate files to the correct location, and one part of the install is applying permissions to the registry,and i Just want to check that registry permissions are applied correctly.